# Rails jsonb with store_accessor using multiple fields with same subfield names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Rails 5.1.4 and Postgresql 9.6, and I do have a model named Car with some jsonb fields, but those jsonb fields have same subfields name, for example acceleration has subfields [gasoline,ethanol,diesel] and max_speed has [gasoline,ethanol,diesel] too, also power and torque has these same subfields, I would like to know how to create an edit form and how to use the store_accessor for it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, instead of using store_accessor I did it using fields_for and OpenStruct to edit the data...

`<%= f.fields_for :power, OpenStruct.new(@car.power) do |power| %>`

Then the fields just like:

`<%= power.text_field :gasoline %>
<%= power.text_field :ethanol %>`

And do the same for other fields like max_speed, acceleration, and torque.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem, it seems can solve your problem.
see: https://github.com/yfxie/json_attribute

In your case, assume `json_attribute` is a json type column in `cars` table, then add all the properties you want:

```rb
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_json_attribute :acceleration_gasoline
  has_json_attribute :acceleration_ethanol
  has_json_attribute :acceleration_diesel
  has_json_attribute :max_speed_gasoline
  has_json_attribute :max_speed_ethanol
  has_json_attribute :max_speed_diesel
end
```

In view:

```
<%= form_for(car_instance) ... do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :acceleration_gasoline %>
  <%= f.text_field :acceleration_ethanol %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

hope it will be helpful to you.